# nth-child counting sequence

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple HTML structure, which I want to show only the second DIV with class "entry":

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="highlight">Hightlight</div>
    <div class="entry">Entry 1</div>
    <div class="entry">Entry 2</div>
    <div class="entry">Entry 3</div>
    <div class="entry">Entry 4</div>
</div>
```

Therefore I use `nth-child(x)` pseudo selector trying to achieve it:

```
#wrapper .entry {
    display: none;
}
#wrapper .entry:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

But end up, "Entry 1" shows up instead. How does `:nth-child(x)` count? It ignores the selector `.entry` completely and just count the occurrence of `<div>` class.

Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/rwvzq4sL/)

Comment: If this set always ends on `.entry` class i.e. if the last div is always going to be `.entry` class, then you can probably try `:nth-last-child()` selector and count from last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It ignores the selector `.entry` completely and just count the occurrence of `<div>` class.

That's almost correct. How it works is:

1. it takes all the `div` elements with class `entry`
2. it takes all the `div` elements that are 2nd element of it's parent
3. it takes an intersection of 1) and 2)

What you really want is something like *nth-of-class*, which is not a thing (I think there is a proposal to add it in next version of CSS).

Comment: but `#wrapper .entry:nth-of-type(2)` produces the same result... how can I adjust my CSS to use `nth-of-type` pseudo selector ?

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that the first element is also a `div`. It would work if it was something different. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should do rather this

```
#wrapper .entry { /* hiding first */
    display: none;
}

#wrapper .entry + .entry /* showing second and following */
{
    display: block;
}

#wrapper .entry + .entry + .entry /* hiding third and following */ 
{
   display:none; 
}
```

not that pretty but will work.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwvzq4sL/1/

Comment: sadly I can't use this method. I have to make use of the pattern `an+b` in my case ( I just simplify it for issue illustration purpose )

Comment: But that's the only option with the current state of affairs in CSS. Another option would be to use script/jquery and assign specific class.